# Stop element by scroll position without jumping

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-position, parallax

I try to stop an element moving when a specific scroll position is reached. This is done with JS by adding a CSS "fixed"-class when the scroll position is reached (here: 100px from the top):

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
}
```

In principle this works fine. However the element does not stop immediately. First the element continues scrolling for about half a second or so, then it jumps back - which looks awful. It depends on the browser: Safari is almost perfect while in Edge the effect is worst. The faster you scroll the worse it gets, in particular if stopping not only a div but an image or so.

A working example is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PybbBd

I saw elements stopping on other sites without any jumping. Does anybody know how to do it? Any help is greatly appreciated! No jquery please.

Comment: In the codepen you provided, everything seems to work fine and your javascript is ok... is there any other elements interfering with the div position in your production code ... like a container or a header or any other element

Comment: Hm, I can't find anything interfering in my production code. However on my computer already the codepen example jumps - especially when scrolling fast or on specific browsers like Edge. The jump is a about 50-100% of the red div's height.

Comment: I tried as fast as I can even run the code on Firefox and Edge, it work just fine, the only reason I see that can made the div jump is a container with a 'padding-top' ... A simple 'padding-top:10px' or 'position:relative' can make the child div (the one you're trying to fix) jump when you switch it to 'position:fixed' ... either way I think sharing your production code will help identify the problem in its real context.

Comment: This may have to do with other conditions in your production environment. Scroll is a _very_ expensive place to do work in the browser. If there is a lot of other JavaScript or paint/rendering fighting for the processing time, you may be getting jank. Would be tough to say without seeing the problematic implementation.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answers! I will insert the production code as soon as I'm home. It's kind of strange that nobody sees the effect in the codepen. If anybody does please tell me. Maybe it's only on my computer (however, it's a standard Mac).